# Not sure if I have an issue with blank constraint or Dynamic Scaffolding

Tags: grails, constraints, scaffolding

I have a simple Domain class that has a few properties. I want to allow one of them to be empty. I am using blank:true in my constraints block.

In Config.groovy I have set convertEmptyStringsToNull=false. That I believe will keep my form submission from setting the blank field to null and the submit failing on the implicit nullable check.

I am using Dynamic Scaffolding in my controller.

I have added some data via BootStrap.groovy. One record has a blank field and it saves as I would expect.

I then launch my app and the list shows my bootstapped records, including the one with the blank field.

When I try to create a new record, with the property that accepts blanks, I am getting a "Please fill out this field" validation error. I believe the record should save.

I'm not sure if this is an issue with the scaffolded view, an issue with the blank constraint, or me not understanding how these features should work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since you are using dynamic scaffolding and you don't have views to edit, try adding nullable:true to your property in domain class and then do dynamic scaffolding again.

Comment: Based on your comment, I'm leaning towards creating a new JIRA Defect against dynamic scaffolding and then moving towards static scaffolding.

Comment: did you try my suggestion. Did it helped. Please try it before creating a JIRA.

Comment: Yes I did try your suggestion. It worked. However, there still is a defect as I don't want nulls, I want to allow blanks.

Comment: You don't want nulls and you want to allow blanks , it means you have to keep some default value.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your entry in Config.groovy is:

```
grails.databinding.convertEmptyStringsToNull = false
```

The scaffolding plugin does not take this configurationoption into account and the scaffolded view _form.gsp contains a required="" attribute

```
<g:textField name="name" required="" value="${fooInstance?.name}"/>
```

You need to remove

```
required=""
```

resulting in

```
<g:textField name="name" value="${fooInstance?.name}"/>
```

so that the browser lets you enter an empty value.

Comment: You are correct with the entry in my Config.groovy. The issue is that I'm using Dynamic Scaffolding, not Static, so I don't have a view to edit. Seems like a bug with Dynamic Scaffolding to me. It should be checking the Config.groovy for the convertEmptyStringsToNull=false and then creating the forms.